# Is it possible to invoke a yarn script in a dependency module?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I have a node application which has dependency. This dependency comes with a yarn script defined in the dependency's package.json.

So it's

```
app.js
package.json
node_modules
  my_dep_module
    package.json // contains this line { scripts: { runme: "node util.js" } }
    util.js
```

How can I invoke, if at all, the runme script of my_dep_module from the application (root) context?

Comment: Does it not also define https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json/#bin?

Comment: If you own the dependencies and are looking to run these scripts upon install then you can rename `runme` to either `preinstall` or `postinstall`. These lifecycle scripts are however ignored when `npm install` is run with `--ignore-scripts`.

Comment: @johnsharpe No, there is no bin, because the module provides several different scripts and doesn't provide a single "entry point". Thanks.

Comment: @customcommander Sounds like a workaround. If  I can't figure out another way, I'll give it a shot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As noted in the docs it can describe a map of _multiple_ entry points too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if your dependency wanted to export one or more executable scripts for your use, they'd have added them to their package.json's [bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) field.

Comment: This question has been lingering around for a while and meanwhile I had entirely forgotten about it. In fact your solution is what I've eventually ended using.